# Why is the input characteristic curve almost independent of $V_{\text{CE}}$?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I am studying the Input Characteristic curve in an $n-p-n$ transistor in common emitter configuration (high school level). My book (NCERT) gives the following curve:

[image]

for this circuit diagram:

[image]

I've understood the logical reasoning related to the graph's shape reasonably well. But, my book also states that:

> Since the increase in $V_\text{CE}$ appears as increase in $V_\text{CB}$, its effect on $I_B$ is negligible. As a consequence, input characteristics for various values of $V_\text{CE}$ will give almost identical curves.

I know the equation $V_\text{CE}=V_\text{CB}+V_\text{BE}$, but I am unable to justify the first sentence of the quoted paragraph from this equation alone. So, what is the reason for the first quoted sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means that when you increase the collector-emitter voltage $V_{CE}$, the base-emitter voltage $V_{BE}$ will stay approximately constant and the increase of $V_{CE}$ causes mainly an increase in $V_{CB}$. In a first approximation, the base current $I_B$ depends only on $V_{BE}$. It is mainly due to the base-emitter junction hole current flowing from the base into the emitter which only depends on $V_{BE}$. Thus even in the case where you impose a constant $I_B$, the base-emitter voltage $V_{BE}$ will stay approximately constant and any increase of $V_{CE}$ translates into an increase of  $V_{CB}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not sure what you mean by "increase the collector-emitter voltage V_CE". V_{CE} is simply the _reading_ of the voltmeter. The actual battery here is being denoted by V_CC. I think you meant "increase the V_CC"?

Comment: @GaurangTandon - You are right. You increase $V_{CE}$ by increasing the $V_{CC}$ in this circuit.